# Finding duplicate values in arraylist

Tags: java, search, arraylist, duplicates

I have an `ArrayList<Car>`

For Example

```
class Car{
   String carName;
   int carType;
}
```

Now, I have to find if the list has any cars having same name. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a comparator:

```
public class CarComparator implements Comparator<Car>
{
    public int compare(Car c1, Car c2)
    {
        return c1.carName.compareTo(c2.carName);
    }
}
```

Now add all the cars of the `ArrayList` to a `SortedSet`, preferably `TreeSet`; if there are duplicates add to the list of duplicates:

```
List<Car> duplicates = new ArrayList<Car>();
Set<Car> carSet = new TreeSet<Car>(new CarComparator());
for(Car c : originalCarList)
{
    if(!carSet.add(c))
    {
        duplicates.add(c);
    }
}
```

Finally in your `duplicates` you will have all the duplicates.

Comment: Why not using `HashSet`. It provides o(1) for all operations while your choice `TreeSet` is o(logn). Am I wrong?

Comment: With Java 8 flavour:


` 
  Set<Integer> duplication = Sets.newHashSet();
        Stream.of(car1, car2, car3).sorted([comparator]).reduce((car, car2) -> {
            if (car.equals(car2)) {
                duplication.add(car2);
            }
            return car2;
        });
        System.out.println(duplication);
`

Answer (score 8):

If you have

```
class Car{
   String carName;
   int carType;
}
```

and

```
List<Car> list;
```

that contains a list of cars, then you could have a method like

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(List<Car> p_cars) {
    final List<String> usedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Car car : p_cars) {
        final String name = car.carName;

        if (usedNames.contains(name)) {
            return true;
        }

        usedNames.add(name);
    }

    return false;
}
```

to find out whether the list of cars have cars with duplicate names.

Comment: Generally speaking `usedNames` must be a `HashSet` otherwise you get O(n) complexity of each check. With `HashSet` you get O(1).

Comment: @Peri461 that was the title, question was "I have to find if the list has any cars having same name"

Comment: Okay fair enough, I apologize.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
List<Car> cars = getCars();
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
for (Car car:cars) {
  if (names.contains(car.getName()) {
    duplicate(car);   // some magic handler
  } else {
    names.add(car.getName());
  }
}
```

Note: this will give you the car names that are duplicate. A follow on would be extracting all cars with those names from the list (if you need the Car objects)

Comment: This solution is way better than best voted solution. This is o(n) algorithm with o(n) space but the other solution is o(nlogn)

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your `Car` class and use a `Set` implementation such as `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: I cant touch the car object..I just the arraylist of Car object then i've to find if any cars in the list has the same name......

Answer (score 0):

I did a similiar program that shows you the words that where repeated in an ArrayList (also it shows the arraylist content and the larger string)

Oh, by the way, variables, and other stuff like comments are in spanish, cause I speak spanish:/ but, if you see the code you can see that I resolved the problem with 2 bucles for!

```
public void mostrarDiecisiete() {


        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String sss = "";

        System.out.println("");

        while (!sss.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")) {

            System.out.print("Ingrese un string: ");
            sss = sc.nextLine();
            if (!sss.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")) {
                array.add(sss);
            }
        }

        int mayor = 0;
        Iterator it = array.iterator();
        String s = "";
        boolean repetir = true;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Posicion: " + i + " del array: " + array.get(i) + " " + "\n");

            if (array.get(i).length() > mayor) {

                mayor = array.get(i).length();

                s = array.get(i);

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {


            System.out.println("vuelta nro: " + i + " del primer for");
            if(j==array.size()){

                j=0;//inicializa de nuevo j en cero si j alcanzo el tamaño del array
                j=i;//inicializa j en el numero de vuelta del primer for, para luego sumarle uno mas asi siempre compara con el siguiente
            }
            for (j++; j < array.size(); j++) {//empieza a comparar con uno mas adelante siempre

                if (array.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(array.get(j))) {//si el array de la posicion i se repite entre la 1 y la ultima de la pos j

                    System.out.println("el string " + array.get(i) + " se repite en la posicion " + j);

                    array2.add(array.get(i)); // se agrega a array2



                } else {
                    System.out.println("String: " + array.get(i) + " no se repite con la posicion " + j);



                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print(
                "el array es: " + array);

        System.out.println(
                "");

        System.out.println(
                "El array mas largo es: " + s + " y tiene " + mayor + " caracteres");

        System.out.println(
                "");

        System.out.println(
                "Los Strings repetidos son" + array2);

    }

}
```

This is my output:

```
Ingrese un string: vaca
Ingrese un string: perro
Ingrese un string: dinosaurio
Ingrese un string: gato
Ingrese un string: cebra
Ingrese un string: DiNoSauRiO
Ingrese un string: VACA
Ingrese un string: hamster
Ingrese un string: gato
Ingrese un string: canario
Ingrese un string: elefante
Ingrese un string: tortuga
Ingrese un string: fin

Posicion: 0 del array: vaca 

Posicion: 1 del array: perro 

Posicion: 2 del array: dinosaurio 

Posicion: 3 del array: gato 

Posicion: 4 del array: cebra 

Posicion: 5 del array: DiNoSauRiO 

Posicion: 6 del array: VACA 

Posicion: 7 del array: hamster 

Posicion: 8 del array: gato 

Posicion: 9 del array: canario 

Posicion: 10 del array: elefante 

Posicion: 11 del array: tortuga 

vuelta nro: 0 del primer for

String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 1
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 2
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 3
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 4
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 5
el string vaca se repite en la posicion 6
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 7
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 8
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 9
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 10
String: vaca no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 1 del primer for
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 2
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 3
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 4
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 5
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 6
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 7
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 8
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 9
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 10
String: perro no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 2 del primer for
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 3
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 4
el string dinosaurio se repite en la posicion 5
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 6
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 7
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 8
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 9
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 10
String: dinosaurio no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 3 del primer for
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 4
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 5
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 6
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 7
el string gato se repite en la posicion 8
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 9
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 10
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 4 del primer for
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 5
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 6
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 7
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 8
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 9
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 10
String: cebra no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 5 del primer for
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 6
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 7
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 8
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 9
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 10
String: DiNoSauRiO no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 6 del primer for
String: VACA no se repite con la posicion 7
String: VACA no se repite con la posicion 8
String: VACA no se repite con la posicion 9
String: VACA no se repite con la posicion 10
String: VACA no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 7 del primer for
String: hamster no se repite con la posicion 8
String: hamster no se repite con la posicion 9
String: hamster no se repite con la posicion 10
String: hamster no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 8 del primer for
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 9
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 10
String: gato no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 9 del primer for
String: canario no se repite con la posicion 10
String: canario no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 10 del primer for
String: elefante no se repite con la posicion 11
vuelta nro: 11 del primer for

el array es: [vaca, perro, dinosaurio, gato, cebra, DiNoSauRiO, VACA, hamster, gato, canario, elefante, tortuga]

El array mas largo es: dinosaurio y tiene 10 caracteres

Los Strings repetidos son[vaca, dinosaurio, gato]  

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 48 seconds)
```