# Check whether an array list contains a value more than once in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an arraylist in which i am storing a list of values. I have to check whether the list contains the same value more than once..And i need only the non-repeating values.. How can i check the number of existences of a value in array list??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: post your code.. for more understanding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist

Comment: @Raghunandan : thanks.. but i need the duplicate value.. how can i get that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281352/finding-duplicate-values-in-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 ArrayList<String>numbers= new ArrayList<String>();

numbers.add("1");
numbers.add("2");
numbers.add("1");
numbers.add("3");


int count= Collections.frequency(numbers, "1");
```

In this way count returns 2.

Answer (score 1):

use

[public static int frequency(Collection c,
                        Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

to get frequency of an object in a collection(arraylist).