# Finding duplicates in a List ignoring a field

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I've got a `List` of Persons and I want to find duplicate entries, consindering all fields except `id`. So using the `equals()`-method (and in consequence `List.contains()`), because they take `id` into consideration.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private int age;
    private long id;
}
```

Modifying the `equals()` and `hashCode()`-methods to ignore the `id` field are not an option because other parts of the code rely on this.

What's the most efficient way in Java to sort out the duplicates if I want to ignore the `id` field?

Comment: Create a custom `Comparator<Person>` and use a `TreeSet<Person>`.

Comment: Perhaps use `Set` with a custom `Comparator`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281352/finding-duplicate-values-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a [`Comparator<Person>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to implement your natural-key ordering and then use a binary-search based deduplication. [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) will give you this ability out of the box.

Note that [`Comparator<T>.compare(a, b)` must fulfil](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#method_summary) the usual antisymmetry, transitivity, consistency and reflexivity requirements or the binary search ordering will fail. You should also make it null-aware (e.g. if the firstname field of one, other or both are null).

A simple natural-key comparator for your Person class is as follows (it is a static member class as you haven't shown if you have accessors for each field).

```
public class Person {
    public static class NkComparator implements Comparator<Person>
    {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
        {
            if (p1 == null || p2 == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            if (p1 == p2) return 0;
            int i = nullSafeCompareTo(p1.firstname, p2.firstname);
            if (i != 0) return i;
            i = nullSafeCompareTo(p1.lastname, p2.lastname);
            if (i != 0) return i;
            return p1.age - p2.age;
        }
        private static int nullSafeCompareTo(String s1, String s2)
        {
            return (s1 == null)
                    ? (s2 == null) ? 0 : -1
                    : (s2 == null) ? 1 : s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    }
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private int age;
    private long id;
}
```

You can then use it to generate a unique list. Use the [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)) method which returns `true` if and only if the element didn't already exist in the set:

```
List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>();
TreeSet<Person> nkIndex = new TreeSet<Person>(new Person.NkComparator());
for (Person p : originalList)
    if (nkIndex.add(p)) newList.add(p); // to generate a unique list
```

or swap the final line for this line to output duplicates instead

```
    if (nkIndex.add(p)) newList.add(p);
```

Whatever you do, don't use `remove` on your original list while you are enumerating it, that's why these methods add your unique elements to a new list.

If you are just interested in a unique list, and want to use as few lines as possible:

```
TreeSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>(new Person.NkComparator());
set.addAll(originalList);
List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>(set);
```

Comment: `compare` throws an NPE if `p1` is `null` but `p2` isn't.

Comment: @pbabcdefp. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): *Unlike Comparable, a comparator may optionally permit comparison of null arguments, while maintaining the requirements for an equivalence relation.*. I would interpret that as saying that throwing NPE from `compare` is optional if you decide that `null` has a natural sort order. My edited answer does show how to throw that for the input arguments, though.

Answer (score 3):

As **@LuiggiMendoza** suggested in the comments:

You could create a custom `Comparator` class that compares two `Person` objects for equality, ignoring their ids.

```
class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    // wraps the compareTo method to compare two Strings but also accounts for NPE
    int compareStrings(String a, String b) {
        if(a == b) {           // both strings are the same string or are null
          return 0;
        } else if(a == null) { // first string is null, result is negative
            return -1;
        } else if(b == null){  // second string is null, result is positive
            return 1;
        } else {               // no strings are null, return the result of compareTo
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {

        // comparisons on Person objects themselves
        if(p1 == p2) {                 // Person 1 and Person 2 are the same Person object
            return 0;
        }
        if(p1 == null && p2 != null) { // Person 1 is null and Person 2 is not, result is negative
            return -1;
        }
        if(p1 != null && p2 == null) { // Person 1 is not null and Person 2 is, result is positive
            return 1;
        }

        int result = 0;

        // comparisons on the attributes of the Persons objects
        result = compareStrings(p1.firstname, p2.firstname);
        if(result != 0) {   // Persons differ in first names, we can return the result
            return result;
        }
        result = compareStrings(p1.lastname, p2.lastname);
        if(result != 0) {  // Persons differ in last names, we can return the result
            return result;
        }

        return Integer.compare(p1.age, p2.age); // if both first name and last names are equal, the comparison difference is in their age
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `TreeSet` structure with this custom `Comparator` and, for example, make a simple method that eliminates the duplicate values.

```
List<Person> getListWithoutDups(List<Person> list) {
    List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    TreeSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>(new PersonComparator()); // use custom Comparator here

    // foreach Person in the list
    for(Person person : list) {
        // if the person isn't already in the set (meaning it's not a duplicate)
        // add it to the set and the new list
        if(!set.contains(person)) {
            set.add(person);
            newList.add(person);
        }
        // otherwise it's a duplicate so we don't do anything
    }

    return newList;
}
```

The `contains` operation in the `TreeSet`, [**as the documentation says**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), **"provides guaranteed log(n) time cost"**.

The method I suggested above take `O(n*log(n))` time since we are performing the `contains` operation on each list element but it also uses `O(n)` space for creating a new list and the `TreeSet`.

If your list is quite large (space is quite important) but you processing speed isn't an issue, then instead of adding each non-duplicate to the list, you could remove each duplicate that is found:

```
 List<Person> getListWithoutDups(List<Person> list) {
    TreeSet<Person> set = new TreeSet<Person>(new PersonComparator()); // use custom Comparator here
    Person person;
    // for every Person in the list
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        person = list.get(i);
        // if the person is already in the set (meaning it is a duplicate)
        // remove it from the list
        if(set.contains(person) { 
            list.remove(i);
            i--; // make sure to accommodate for the list shifting after removal
        } 
        // otherwise add it to the set of non-duplicates
        else {
            set.add(person);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Since each `remove` operation on a list takes `O(n)` time (because the list gets shifted each time an element is deleted), and each `contains` operation takes `log(n)` time, this approach would be `O(n^2 log(n))` in time.

However, the space complexity would be halved since we only create the `TreeSet` and not the second list.

Comment: Your comparator is not antisymmetric, are you sure it will work with TreeSet? It isn't null-safe either.

Comment: You are correct. My intention was not to crowd up the code with all the error checking and just show the main logic. I added invalid/null data checking.

Comment: Your comparator still doesn't work. And your `getListWithoutDups` method is broken too.

Comment: I see your answer and it is a much cleaner and efficient way of doing this, +1. I don't seem to follow you on my errors though. Could you give an example?

Comment: In `getListWithoutDups` lets say you remove the 0th element. All elements shift up. Now you increment `i` and so skip the "new" 0th element. Always be very careful when iterating a collection at the same time as mutating it. For the comparator it needs to be antisymmetric: it can't just return -1 for "not equals", it must be -ve or +ve, and it must reverse if you reverse the input arguments p1 and p2.

Comment: Ok, I believe i fixed it. Thanks for the very useful pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using a `Comparator` to do this. It is quite difficult to write a legal `compare()` method based on the other fields.

I think a better solution would be to create a class `PersonWithoutId` like so:

```java
public PersonWithoutId {
  private String firstname, lastname;
  private int age;
  // no id field
  public PersonWithoutId(Person original) { /* copy fields from Person */ }
  @Overrides public boolean equals() { /* compare these 3 fields */ }
  @Overrides public int hashCode() { /* hash these 3 fields */ }
}
```

Then, given a `List<Person>` called `people` you can do this:

```
Set<PersonWithoutId> set = new HashSet<>();
for (Iterator<Person> i = people.iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
    if (!set.add(new PersonWithoutId(i.next())))
        i.remove();
```

**Edit**

As others have pointed out in the comments, this solution is not ideal as it creates a load of objects for the garbage collector to deal with. But this solution is **much** faster than a solution using a `Comparator` and a `TreeSet`. Keeping a `Set` in order takes time and it has nothing to do with the original problem. I tested this on `List`s of 1,000,000 instances of `Person` constructed using

```
new Person(
    "" + rand.nextInt(500),  // firstname 
    "" + rand.nextInt(500),  // lastname
    rand.nextInt(100),       // age
    rand.nextLong())         // id
```

and found this solution to be roughly twice as fast as a solution using a `TreeSet`. (Admittedly I used `System.nanoTime()` rather than proper benchmarking).

So how can you do this efficiently without creating loads of unnecessary objects? Java doesn't make it easy. One way would be to write two new methods in `Person`

```
boolean equalsIgnoringId(Person other) { ... }

int hashCodeIgnoringId() { ... }
```

and then to write a custom implementation of `Set<Person>` where you basically cut and paste the code for `HashSet` except you replace `equals()` and `hashCode()` by `equalsIgnoringId()` and `hashCodeIgnoringId()`  .

In my humble opinion, the fact that you can create a `TreeSet` that uses a `Comparator`, but not a `HashSet` that uses custom versions of `equals`/`hashCode` is a serious flaw in the language.

Comment: If you write a custom comparator that the List doesn't know about it won't change the ordering of the list. Creating a derived class just for this purpose isn't a good idea: this is about alternative equality and ordering (actually a natural-key ordering instead of the primary key ordering) so a comparator is a perfect tool to use. Creating a new type and gumming up the GC with all the casts isn't a good idea.

Comment: I've taken out the line about changing the order. Technically you could do this using a TreeSet. But the idea that a Comparator is the perfect tool is simply wrong - the problem is about equality, not order. I agree that my solution has its faults, but there is no satisfactory solution.

Comment: I like your new argument but when I tried performance testing your solution the results depend on duplicate %, list size, steady-state vs startup, and even JVM. I get similar results to you with your `rand` ranges, but saw both speed up and slow down depending on the exact conditions. tldr: performance testing [is hard](http://buytaert.net/files/oopsla07-georges.pdf)

Comment: @AndyBrown I know my approach to testing was very lazy - thank you for that link. I will read it as I know nothing about performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java `HashMap` using `<K,V>` pairs. `Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>()`. Also, some form of Comparator implementation to go with. If you check with containsKey or containsValue methods and find out you already have something (i.e. you are trying to add a duplicate, keep them in your original list. Otherwise, pop them out. In this way, you will end up with a list with the elements that were duplicates in your original list. TreeSet<,>will be another option, but I haven't used it yet so cannot offer advice.