# Multiple NULL addition into a List in Java

Tags: java, list, concurrency, null, addition

I have 2 lists and want to copy some element from one to another, i.e. there are old and new employees list I need to union 2 lists and delete the elements that include to the old list but not include in the new one.

I could solve the part of getting the union and intersection by using TreeSet and override the equals and hashcode functions of the Employees class....

Now, I want to exclude the elements that are in the old but not in the new and add them to the "deletedList"....which I got "ConcurrentModificationException"

I tried this instead of "iterator" but the same result: for(Employees e : employeesListDB)

Also I tried "CopyOnWriteArrayList" instead of "ArrayList" but no change!!

but the problem now that at the initialization of the empty list "deletedList" it is filled with multiple null elements before the add function!

Here is the code:

```
List<Employees> employeesListDB = this.findAll();     

Set<Employees> empSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
empSet.addAll(employeesList);

List<Employees> deletedList = new ArrayList<Employees>();
Employees e = new Employees();

ListIterator<Employees> itr = employeesListDB.listIterator();    
for(itr.hasNext()) { 
  e = (Employees)itr.next();
  if(!empSet.contains(e)) {
    deletedList.add(e);
  }               
}
```

A counter Example:

The oldlist "employeesListDB" the employees list from the database:

```
[  
    {  
        "email":"mariam.moustafa@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"sara.ahmed@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"ali.hassan@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"hoosen.imam-ally@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"allan.randall@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"nishaan.maharaj@x.com"
    }
]
```

The new list to be added:

```
[  
    {  
        "email":"ali.moustafa@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"sara.ahmed@x.com"
    },
    {  
        "email":"emad.hamed@x.com"
    }
```

]

The deleted list that I want:

> [
>           {
>               "email":"mariam.moustafa@x.com"
>           },
>           {
>               "email":"ali.hassan@x.com"
>           },
>           {
>               "email":"hoosen.imam-ally@x.com"
>           },
>           {
>               "email":"allan.randall@x.com"
>           },
>           {
>               "email":"nishaan.maharaj@x.com"
>           }
>       ]

Sara mail will be updated...

Employee class has two fields {id,email} the new list (the list to be added to the db) is a list of only emails, id field are not recognized yet but the old list has the complete bean fields ...to compare between these 2 list I should override the Comparator to ignore the id field; [Finding duplicates in a List ignoring a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926111/finding-duplicates-in-a-list-ignoring-a-field)

JUST I need to know, why when I use set.add operation, it adds the unique emails only! the original size of the list was 36 elements after adding it into  a set it becomes only 16!!

```
 Set<Employees> oldSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        oldSet.addAll(employeesListDB);

        Set<Employees> newSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        newSet.addAll(employeesList);


        Set<Employees> deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);
```

Comment: I tried this instead of "iterator" but the same result:
for(Employees e : employeesListDB)

Comment: Also I tried "CopyOnWriteArrayList" instead of "ArrayList" but no change!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Tip: You can edit your own question, so you might add the above comments to it instead of creating comments for them.

Comment: Your code looks fine - please post a complete example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I am editing the question and will rewrite in clear way...it is urgent

Comment: It is very unclear...what are you trying, why are you trying and then so many why's. Does that help?

Comment: with your actual logic you add (max!) 1 item to `deleteList` . you need a loop `while(itr.hasNext)` instead of `if(itr.hasNext())`

Comment: Please update your question with an example containing two lists, one new and one old, along with what the union you want to be.  This will make it exponentially easier for us to help you.

Comment: I think your whole question is unclear. Why do you need the TreeSet? just go through the oldList, check if the item is in the newList. if not, add it to the deleteList.

Comment: I problem that Employee class has two fields {id,email} the new list (the list to be added to the db) is a list of only emails, id field are not recognized yet but the old list has the complete bean fields ...to compare between these 2 list I should override the Comparator to ignore the id field

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة and what should happen if 2 employess (different id) have the same email Adress (unlikely but its possible). And why is your newList (or Set or whatever) not a List<String> or List<Email> but a List<Employee>. if it has no id, it couldnt be a correct Employee

Comment: good question, I already receive a list of emails as a String then I format them with JSON to be a list of Employees to compare a addedit/delete

Comment: but why don't you just go through the oldList, check if the email is present in the List of Emails (without converting it to an Employee) you can save if a email is found in an old employee. If it is not present in the List -> add the employee to the remove List. And at the end remove all emails which you saved during the loop from the newList. For every item which remains, create a new Employee

Comment: Yes, I can check if the new email is already exist then no change but what is about an old email that is needed to remove and a new email that is needed to add...

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة see my last edit of my answer. this should work

Comment: I am trying it right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way (Made a small TestCase):

```
private static Employee createEmployee(String string) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmail(string);
    return employee;
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    List<String> newMails = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Employee> oldList = new ArrayList<>();

    oldList.add(createEmployee("mariam.moustafa@x.com"));
    oldList.add(createEmployee("sara.ahmed@x.com"));
    oldList.add(createEmployee("ali.hassan@x.com"));
    oldList.add(createEmployee("hoosen.imam-ally@x.com"));
    oldList.add(createEmployee("allan.randall@x.com"));
    oldList.add(createEmployee("nishaan.maharaj@x.com"));

    newMails.add("ali.moustafa@x.com");
    newMails.add("sara.ahmed@x.com");
    newMails.add("emad.hamed@x.com");

    List<Employee> delete = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> removedMails = new HashSet<>();

    for (Employee emp : oldList) {
        if (!newMails.contains(emp.getEmail())) {
            delete.add(emp);
        }
        removedMails.add(emp.getEmail());
    }
    newMails.removeAll(removedMails);
    // remove emploeyees in delete
    oldList.removeAll(delete);

    // Create employee for left MAils
    for (String newMail : newMails) {
        oldList.add(createEmployee(newMail));
    }

    //Old and new Employees
    for (Employee emp : oldList) {
        System.out.println(emp.getEmail());
    }
```

}

simple Employee class:

```
class Employee {
String email;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

output:

```
sara.ahmed@x.com
ali.moustafa@x.com
emad.hamed@x.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GriFlo for the complete solution :)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need all elements that are contained by old set and not contained by new set.

For this purpose you can use [Guava Sets#difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) method:

```
Set<Employees> deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);
```

Test with your data:

```
Set<String> oldEmployees = Sets.newHashSet("mariam.moustafa@x.com", "sara.ahmed@x.com", "ali.hassan@x.com", "hoosen.imam-ally@x.com", "allan.randall@x.com", "nishaan.maharaj@x.com");
Set<String> newEmployees = Sets.newHashSet("ali.moustafa@x.com", "sara.ahmed@x.com", "emad.hamed@x.com");

Set<String> diff = Sets.difference(oldEmployees, newEmployees);

System.out.println(diff);
```

Result:

```
[nishaan.maharaj@x.com, mariam.moustafa@x.com, ali.hassan@x.com, allan.randall@x.com, hoosen.imam-ally@x.com]
```

Comment: A simple answer without a gazillion comments is exactly what this question needs right now.

Comment: newSet may have new elements that are not already exist in the oldSet, SO i need to union then subtract the difference old-new

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة, new elements in new set will be ignored and will not pass to diff result, [Sets#difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set))

Comment: It works fine..but still I need to modify the algorithm...thanks in advance

Comment: JUST I need to know, why when I use set.add operation, it adds the unique emails only! the original size of the list was 36 elements after adding it into  a set it becomes only 16!!

 Set<Employees> oldSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        oldSet.addAll(employeesListDB);
        
        Set<Employees> newSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        newSet.addAll(employeesList);
        
        
        Set<Employees> deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة, [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)  - A collection that contains no duplicate elements...

Comment: I got this exception while I am trying the final code:

ex = (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException) java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Set<Employees> deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);
        
        Set<Employees> added = Sets.difference(newSet, oldSet);
        
        try{
            oldSet.removeAll(deleted);
            oldSet.addAll(added);        
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

Comment: First - read [THIS](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) -- Returns an **unmodifiable** view of the difference of two sets. 
Second - update your question, your code is very strange

Answer (score 2):

Here is a core Java solution using 2 simple steps:

[**1**] - Create a set `setOld` which contains the first set of emails
[**2**] - Subtract from `setOld` a new set of emails `setNew`

```
Set oldSet<String> = new HashSet<String>();  // original set of email addresses
oldSet.add("mariam.moustafa@x.com");
oldSet.add("sara.ahmed@x.com");
oldSet.add("ali.hassan@x.com");
oldSet.add("hoosen.imam-ally@x.com");
oldSet.add("allan.randall@x.com");
oldSet.add("nishaan.maharaj@x.com");

Set newSet<String> = new HashSet<String>();  // new set of email addresses
newSet.add("ali.moustafa@x.com");
newSet.add("sara.ahmed@x.com");
newSet.add("emad.hamed@x.com");

for (String s : newSet) {
    oldSet.remove(s);     // this will only remove the element if found
}

// display new contents of oldSet
for (String s : oldSet) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output:**

```
mariam.moustafa@x.com
ali.hassan@x.com
hoosen.imam-ally@x.com
allan.randall@x.com
nishaan.maharaj@x.com
```

Comment: It works fine..but still I need to modify the algorithm...thanks in advance

Comment: JUST I need to know, why when I use set.add operation, it adds the unique emails only! the original size of the list was 36 elements after adding it into  a set it becomes only 16!!

 Set<Employees> oldSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        oldSet.addAll(employeesListDB);
        
        Set<Employees> newSet = new TreeSet<Employees>(new EmployeeComparator());
        newSet.addAll(employeesList);
        
        
        Set<Employees> deleted = Sets.difference(oldSet, newSet);

Comment: Yes, a `Set` cannot, by definition, have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

> the empty list filled with multiple null elements before the add
>   function!

This is becuase you're using the `ArrayList` which contains the following constant:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
```

Which mean when you create the `ArrayList<T>` with the `new` operator you actually create an `Array` of `T` which contains 10 `null`s (It's contained as `private transient Object[] elementData` field).

The [JLS said](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is
>   used:
>
> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> [...]
>
> **For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.**

Comment: Yes, that exactly what i get, 9 null element and then my element...so what type should I use?!

Comment: @مريمقدالحياة It doesn't depend on what type you use. If you want to avoid the nulls be appeared you may consider to use `LinkedList<T>` instead.

Comment: I tried to change to "LinkedList<Employees" the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Use List removeAll method.** You will need to override equals method in your Employees class. PFB sample snippet based on employee id, you will need to modify it to fit based on email id:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringArray {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Employee> oldList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        oldList.add(new Employee(1));
        oldList.add(new Employee(2));
        oldList.add(new Employee(3));
        oldList.add(new Employee(4));

        List<Employee> newList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        newList.add(new Employee(3));
        newList.add(new Employee(4));
        newList.add(new Employee(5));
        newList.add(new Employee(6));

        oldList.removeAll(newList);

        System.out.println("Printing delete list");
        for (Employee employee : oldList)
            System.out.println(employee);

        System.out.println("Printing updated list");
        for (Employee employee : newList)
            System.out.println(employee);
    }
}

public class Employee {
    private int id; 

    public Employee(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + this.id + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {       

        if (o == this)
            return true;        

        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) 
            return false; 

        Employee c = (Employee) o;         

        return this.id == c.id;     
    }   
}
```