# convert List<String> to Set in CASE INSENSITIVE Manner-Java 6

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a list which contains Strings ABC:123,abc:123 ;when I am converting it to Set its giving me 2 different elements.Is there a one liner way to convert this List to Set ignoring the case so that my Set contains ABC:123 only.` But if the input List contains ABC:123a4,abc:1234A4 it should give me 2 different elements in the Set : ABC:123a4,ABC:1234A4 
I know this can be done spliting the list elements on ":" first and converting the abc to all uppercase and adding them to new list and then the rest.But just wanted to know if there a better way (small lines of code) to do that.Thanks for any brain storming ideas in advance.

```
List<String> memlist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(memberList.split(",")));
Set<String> memberSet = new HashSet<String>(memlist );
memlist = new ArrayList<String>(memberSet);
```

Comment: Either extend `Set` and override its `add (E e)` method; or a wrapper around it. In this case I recommend the first. What @redflar3 said works just as fine.

Comment: will convert all strings to a common case before inserting solve your problem?

Comment: @redflar3 based on his comment on SQL hacks answer, the answer is no.

Comment: Are all the elements in this format? Like three letters and a colon and then one letter and one number? You need to be more specific about your input values.

Comment: nope...the format is <Only alphabets>:<anycharacterincluding : >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is wrong with actually creating a little `Model` class to take care of all possible cases?

```
final class Model{
 final String firstPart;
 final String secondPart;
 final int hashCode;
  Model(String s){
   String[] splitted=s.split(":");
   firstPart=splitted[0];
   secondPart=splitted[1];
   hashCode=Objects.hash(firstPart.toLowerCase(),secondPart);

  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
   String[] splitted=o.toString().split(":");
   return firstPart.equalsIgnoreCase(splitted[0]) && secondPard.equals(splitted[1]);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
   return hashCode;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return firstPart+":"+secondPart;
  }
}
```

now create a set and etc:

```
Set<Model> set =new HashSet<Model>();
```

Comment: The `Model` idea is the same as the wrapper. Your `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations look cleaner, though.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula you are right mate, sorry I didn't go through the detail of your implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `TreeSet` with the `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` flag set.

```
    String startingString = "ABC:123,abc:123";
    List<String> caseSensitiveList = Arrays.asList(startingString.split(","));
    Set<String> caseInsensitiveSet = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    caseInsensitiveSet.addAll(caseSensitiveList);

    for(String caseInsensitiveString : caseInsensitiveSet){
        System.out.println(caseInsensitiveString);
    }
```

This code, when run, gives me the output:

```
ABC:123
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a `TreeSet` when sorting is not involved in the problem at all.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula you need to use a `TreeSet` to use that override, as far as I know.

Comment: @MikeElofson No you don't. You can use a `HashSet` where you just make all elements upper case first, or you can write a new class that wraps a string and ignores case in the equals and hashCode methods. Using a `TreeSet` when it is not needed is bad for performance as the time complexity of all the basic operations is `O(log n)` rather than `O(1)`.

Comment: @MikeElofson I understand that. That's why I'd go with a different solution. You're using a `TreeSet` because of this little detail, not because of what a `TreeSet`, in fact, is. With this solution OP would get a slower and (uselessly) sorted `Set`, instead of his original `HashSet`.

Comment: This is a nice out-of-the-box solution. Forcing clients to do toUpperCase before each insertion is perhaps more efficient but it's also more error prone. You could wrap a HashSet in your own data structure that makes sure this is done upon insertion, but you would either have to A) extend HashSet (and take care to override a lot of methods to maintain the invariant) or B) wrap a HashSet and have to write a lot of forwarding methods. Until an application is benchmarked and it's certain that O(log n) constitutes a bottle neck, I think a TreeSet based one-liner is preferrable.

Comment: @aioobe The problem here is that `HashSet` is so inflexible. They allow you to use a custom `Comparator` **or** the natural ordering for a `TreeSet`, but for some inexplicable reason `HashSet` forces you to use `equals` and `hashCode` rather than allowing you to specify the notion of equality you want for the set. I've ranted about this at length before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926111/finding-duplicates-in-a-list-ignoring-a-field

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
memberList.split(",")
```

with

```
memberList.toUpperCase().split(",")
```

Comment: that will convert ABC:123a4,abc:1234A4 as well as same element. I only want the first part i.e. before : to be case insensitive

Comment: @Bidisha Then add this crucial detail to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution is the one suggested by @SQLHacks. But then you said `ABC:123a4` must be different from `abc:1234A4`. I guess the only solution now is to create a wrapper for the `String` objects and override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method to do what you want, as @PaulBoddington suggested in his comment.

---

This is what I came up with (edited and improved based on @nafas answer):

```
public class StringWrapper {

    private String value;

    private String beforeColon;
    private String afterColon;

    private int hash;

    public StringWrapper(String value) {
        this.value = value;

        String[] splitted = value.split(":");
        beforeColon = splitted[0];
        afterColon = splitted[1];
        hash = Objects.hash(beforeColon.toUpperCase(), afterColon);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof StringWrapper) {
            StringWrapper other = (StringWrapper) obj;
            return beforeColon.equalsIgnoreCase(other.beforeColon) && afterColon.equals(other.afterColon);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

And then:

```
    // this method is just to help you building a List<StringWrapper> from your String (memberList variable)
    public static List<StringWrapper> split(String string, String regex) {
        List<StringWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String element : string.split(regex)) {
            list.add(new StringWrapper(element));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String memberList = "ABC:123,abc:123,ABC:123a4,ABC:123A4";

        List<StringWrapper> memlist = new ArrayList<>(split(memberList, ","));
        Set<StringWrapper> memberSet = new HashSet<>(memlist);
        memlist = new ArrayList<StringWrapper>(memberSet);

        for (StringWrapper element : memlist) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
```

If you run this, you get as output the following:

```
ABC:123a4
ABC:123A4
ABC:123
```

`abc:123` is out but `ABC:123a4` and `ABC:123A4` are both present.

You can make things even easier changing the static `split` method to create the `Set` for you. The reason I didn't do that was to make things look familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Java 8 one liner

```
Set<String> memberSet = memlist.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It will go through all strings in memlist convert them to uppercase and put them to a set.

That means of course that if your list contains "abc:123" but not "ABC:123", you will still get "ABC:123" in the set.