# How to get common values from arraylists?

Tags: android

I have six values that I have stored store in ArrayList..
How to get common values from that array list?

****What I have tried:****

```
    aList1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
        aList1.add(value1);
        aList1.add(value2);
        aList1.add(value3);
        aList1.add(value4);
        aList1.add(value5);
        aList1.add(value6);      

     aList2 = new ArrayList<String>();    
            aList2.add(value1);
            aList2.add(value2);
            aList2.add(value3);
            aList2.add(value4);
            aList2.add(value5);
            aList2.add(value6);

String []sCommon = alist1.compare(alist2)    

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + sCommon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Collection#retainAll().**

```
listA.retainAll(listB);
```

listA now contains only the elements which are also contained in listB.
If you want to avoid that changes are being affected in listA, then you need to create a new one.

```
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(listA);
common.retainAll(listB);
```

common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.

Answer (score 0):

check this you can get duplicate value from ArrayList.

[Finding duplicate values in arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281352/finding-duplicate-values-in-arraylist)

other way you can remove duplicate element like this

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
// add elements to al, including duplicates
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
hs.addAll(al);
al.clear();
al.addAll(hs);
```

Hop it help you